# C# no coercion operator is defined between types anonymous object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm currently working on a LINQ query in an ASP.NET 4.5 application. I try to query 2 lists from different talbles, union the results and return an IQueryable of the data type of the first table.

The tables in my database have similar fields, so i can just select into an anonymous object what I need.

My query looks like this:

```
var coolStuff = ctx.CoolStuffTable.Select(x => new
{
    PK = x.PK,
    CreationDate = x.CreationDate,
    ModificationDate = x.ModificationDate,
    Titel = x.Title,
    Visible = x.Visible
});

var niceStuff = ctx.NiceStuffTable.Select(x => new
{
    PK = x.PK,
    CreationDate = x.CreationDate,
    ModificationDate = x.ModificationDate,
    Title = x.Title,
    Visible = x.Visible
});

var result = coolStuff.Union(nicelStuff)
        .Where(i => i.Visible);

var result = result.Cast<CoolStuffTable>(); // the LinqToSQL class of thable CoolStuffTable is also called CoolStuffTable
```

It looks actually quite good, nevertheless I'm getting this stra

**No coercion operator is defined between types**

Of course, I could write a view in SQL server, but I'd like to solve this in LINQ...

Do you know how to query 2 different tables, union them and return them as of type table 1 (CoolStuffTable)?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Use projection. Maybe write a conversion method. There's no duck-type-implicit-cast-conversion built into the language.

Answer (score 2):

You need to project to `CoolStuffTable` again like

```
var result = coolStuff.Union(nicelStuff)
                      .Where(i => i.Visible)
                      .Select(s => new CoolStuffTable
                        {
                               PK = s.PK,
                               CreationDate = s.CreationDate,
                               ModificationDate = s.ModificationDate,
                               Title = s.Title,
                               Visible = s.Visible
                        });
```